# Windows icon cache does not exist

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons, cache

I've just performed a fresh install of Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit, and have installed all updates and SP1. After installing IObit Smart Defrag, I noticed the icon for that software was the generic application icon in Windows, rather than that of the actual software. So naturally, I assumed I need to rebuild the icon cache, as is widely explained all over, and I've done it a million times.

However, when I navigate to `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\`, There is no file `IconCache.db`. I have restarted and this file still does not exist. Obviously I replaced `[Username]` with the actual username, and have selected to show hidden/system files. I've even tried a command prompt, and that too reports that the file does not exist when I tried deleting it from there. So this file really isn't there.

What is wrong and how do I fix this? It seems this new Windows install has no icon cache at all, and I am seeing random other applications showing the same generic icon...

**EDIT**

Adding to the confusion... These applications which are showing the generic Windows icons indeed do have a proper icon. I right-click the EXE and go to Properties, and it has the correct icon displayed there. However, across Windows Explorer, including the Taskbar, these application icons are not showing. And that cache file does not exist.

**EDIT**

I've done a trial... I created a new user account on this system (Administrator) as this cache is on a per-user basis. Unfortunately this new user also has no icon cache. It's not that I just can't see the file - the file really isn't there, no matter what method I try to delete it (Windows Explorer, Command Prompt, even my own custom code).

**EDIT**

As suggested in comments in an answer, I checked the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\` to only discover everything is missing from here. The only key here is `Directory`, whereas another normal install has hundreds of file extensions listed here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine did a trial... He opened the Control Panel, and opened Default Programs. Windows appeared to do some work for a minute before it brought up the list of extensions. Then I checked the registry, and these registry entries were there. Once I rebooted Windows, BAM `IconCache.db` is there. Also, all the programs which weren't showing their proper icons were fixed. It appears the Windows Install didn't perform this task, and it had to be done manually through the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Some files will not show even if you show hidden.

To make sure you delete the icon cache, do this:

1. Open task manager.
2. In the Processes tab, click on explorer.exe and click End Process. You then get a confirmation dialog. Click "End Process" to confirm.
3. From the File menu (don't close task manager yet), choose New Task (Run...).
4. Run a command prompt (cmd).
5. In there, paste del %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db /a
6. The the command prompt window, then type explorer.exe to reload the explorer and the UI
7. Check now, your icons should be fixed.

Comment: I already tried the command prompt, that's when I concluded the file really does not exist.

Comment: You should check registry file icons (by extension). That will show if something is wrong with the registry. Goto HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts . Check there what is the default icon and what rules apply.

Comment: The only key under the `FileExts` folder is just `Directory`, whereas on a good install there are hundreds of file extensions listed here.

Comment: Check my answer :D

Comment: +1 though for hinting to that registry key, although in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

https://winbuzzer.com/2020/07/31/windows-10-icons-thumbnails-missing-or-blank-heres-how-to-fix-them-with-an-icon-cache-rebuild-xcxwbt/
The first step of this solution fixed this for me. I was having a similar issue, no icon cache to delete or anything and this solution really saved the day.
I know this is an old post but I came across it before the other solution and I figured I would add a link to it from here so anyone else looking for a way to fix the issue can at least find the ohter answer.

Answer (score -2):

Windows 7 64 home (System Builder, but I was sent a replacement disk that was simply Windows 7 64 home. No idea if that makes ANY difference because when putting in that replacement disk, I still had to use my key from the System Builders. I may have had to call MS at the time /shrug)

Anyway...
Yesterday I decided to go into Regedit and delete Ctrl+F :" internet explorer "
(I use chrome and was tired of seeing results of CCleaner results for "internet explorer".

Right away..
In my start menu icons for Calculator, Word, Notepad changed to a blank page (stock?).
In my task bar had the same look for Windows Media, Internet Explorer, and Google Chrome.
*I have already turned off Internet Explorer in the add and remove programs, windows and features, removing the check mark. I also ran CCleaner.. MONTHS ago.. I was still getting results in CCleaner.

There is NO result for C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\IconCache.db
IconCache.db is not there to 'delete'. Not for me Windows 7 64 Home.

*IF you do have IconCache.db found at C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\IconCache.db,  You can make a 1 click button for cleaning it.

I read in another forum ( which is the same as another user said here, but all in one click)...

open notepad,

Copy and Paste the below text so you have a total of 5 lines of text in your notepad:

taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe

cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local

attrib –h IconCache.db

del IconCache.db

start explorer

Save the 5 (FIVE) lines of text and name it: .bat

Save it to desktop.

That icon will look like gears.

Click it.

It is turning off explorer.exe, deleting IconCache.db, starting explorer.exe. (same as another user said here but all in one click)

My screen went black and came back as if I stopped Explorer.exe in Task Manager.

No difference with my icons.( Because IconCache.db is not located there for me on my HOME version )

*Note, when clicking on a broken/blank icon, (I forgot exactly what it said) it had a message pop up about the file is missing or broken.. something like that. So clicking Calculator didn't work. Windows Media in the task bar, didn't work.

What worked for me was to replace the icons. (each icon 1 at a time)

Remember Windows 7 Home 64.

click Start - All Programs - Accessories.
I found Calculator... held left click... dragged it down to the 'page back' arrow and waited... The regular menu opened back up and I dragged it up top to 'pin to start menu' and let go. Calculator dropped in right next to the blank icon Calculator. I then right clicked the blank Calculator and deleted.

I did the same with WordPad, Notepad, Chrome in my task bar (dragged over the icon on my desktop/deleted old blank icon), Windows Media (dragged from Start menu/deleted old blank icon).

Simply put, I dragged the normal looking icons and placed them next to the broken ones.

That is the only thing that worked for me.

I have a feeling Windows 7 HOME does not have the IconCache.db listed for you to delete. I Don't know if that is a 'Professional' feature? Some mentioned they saw it in ' Ultimate ' version. Also, maybe since it is mid 2018 that IconCache.db got moved in some Windows Update that I did. My windows is legit and up to date.

____________Another forum mentioned a resolution  you can try___________
https://www.virtualhelp.me/windows/782-broken-or-missing-icons-in-windows-78

1) Right-click on the desktop and select "Screen Resolution"

2) Under "Advanced Settings" select "Monitor" tab. In the colors drop down, select a value other than what you have now (so if it is "True Color 32 bit" select "True Color 16 bit" and vice-versa).

3) Click "Ok" and and the icons should restore themselves.

4) Once the icons appear, you can repeat the steps 1-3 and revert back to whatever value you've had initially.

---

No idea if it works.

Good luck!

I still see Internet Explorer results in CCleaner ><

Comment: Please edit your answer and just include the steps required to fix the problem. The rest is just distracting commentary.